# Finite number of points inside a disk

Tags: general-topology, geometry, complex-analysis, recreational-mathematics

> Let $n\ge 2$ and suppose that $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n$ are
>   distinct points in the interior of some disk $D$ in the plane. Why is
>   it true that there exists a smaller disk $D'\subseteq D$ such that
>   $D'$ contains **exactly** $n-1$ of these points above?

In other words, we want $D'$ to contain $n-1$ of the points $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n$, and miss one of these points. This fact above was used in the proof of Cauchy's Residue Theorem in my complex analysis class. However, the proof wasn't provided, and the justification for it was kind of handwaving. I would love to see a rigorous proof for this interesting fact.

Any help is much appreciated!

P.S. What area of mathematics would this problem fall? (Topology? Geometry?)

Comment: I don't see how this can be true if $r:=|z_1|=|z_2|=...=|z_n|$. Any disk of radius smaller than $r$ contains none of the points, any disk of radius greater or equal to $r$ contains all of them.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @OliverBraun: The discs don't necessarily have the same centres

Comment: Ok, right, I was thinking about disks with center $0$. Thanks to fretty.
Prism That's no problem, $r$ may be strictly smaller than the radius of the disk $D$. Then all the points are in the interior of $D$. But this is not very relevant since I was forgetting about disks with center other than $0$...

Comment: @OliverBraun: Yeah you are right. Sorry, my comment didn't make sense, so I removed it :)

Comment: If $\large\left\vert z_{1}\right\vert < \left\vert z_{2}\right\vert < \cdots \left\vert z_{n}\right\vert$, just choose a disk with radius $\large r$ such that $\large \left\vert z_{n - 1}\right\vert < r <\left\vert z_{n}\right\vert$ unless $\large \left\vert z_{n - 1}\right\vert = \left\vert z_{n}\right\vert$ as @OliverBraun already pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick all pairs of two pints $(z_i, z_j)$. Draw the perpendicular bisector on this segment.

This way you get at most $\binom{n}{2}$ lines. Pick a point on none of these lines (measure theory shows such a point exists, but there mist be a simpler argument).

This point will have pairwise distinct distances to the $n$ points, and you can easily show that some circle with the centre here will work.

Comment: @StefanH.:  you draw the segment between $z_i$ and $z_j$.  Find the midpoint and draw a line perpendicular to the segment through that point.  It bisects the segment.

Comment: You haven't shown that the circle will be within the original disk $D$.  It will be true for centers near enough the original center, but that needs some argument.  A good approach, though.

Comment: @RossMillikan: enthusiastic (+1) for your second comment. I am having trouble proving that the circle we are constructing will lie inside the original disk $D$. :( If N.S. could expand on that, it would be awesome :)

Comment: @Prism: as all the points are inside $D$, there is one at minimum distance from the boundary. The same argument can be used to say we can choose the center of $D'$ within half that distance and we are home.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Sorry for being dense, but I don't seem to be convinced. Suppose $z_k$ is the point with minimum distance from the boundary, say distance $d_k$. Where is exactly the center of $D'$? Half that distance $d_k$ from which point? If you could expand on that comment, it would be great :) Also, feel free to write in an answer box, so I can upvote it.

Comment: @Prism:  It is half the distance from the center of $D$.  That way the circle doesn't bulge out on one side.  Since there are only finitely many lines, there are points not on any line that are arbitrarily close to the center of $D$ such that no pair of points are at the same distance.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Got it! This makes sense now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you for completing the proof, I typed it while hurrying to a class so left some important details out :)

Answer (score 1):

For ease of notation, let's assume $D$ is centered around the origin, and has radius $r$. Also, w.l.o.g. $z_1$ has maximal modulus (although not necessarily uniquely so).

Consider the disc
$D^\prime = D_{\frac{|z_1|+r}{2}}(\frac{z_1}{|z_1|}\frac{|z_1|-r}{2})$.

Note that for all $z\not\in D^\prime$ we have
$$|z|\geq \left|z-\frac{z_1}{|z_1|}\frac{|z_1|-r}{2}\right| - \left|\frac{z_1}{|z_1|}\frac{|z_1|-r}{2}\right| \geq \frac{|z_1|+r}{2} - \left|\frac{|z_1|-r}{2}\right| = |z_1|,$$
and equality holds only when $z,z_1$ have the same argument (but then, only for $z=z_1$). It follows that $z_1\not\in D^\prime$, and is alone in having this property among $z_1,\ldots,z_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't quite understand this bit: "and equality holds only when $z, z_1$ have the same argument (but then, only for $z=z_1$)". Why does that necessarily follow? Suppose $z_2$ is another point with $|z_1|=|z_2|$, then I don't see why $z_2$ is forced to have the same argument as $z_1$.

Comment: @Prism, that's because for all $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$, $|z+w|=|z|+|w|$ only if $z,w$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah right. That makes sense! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

After a suitable Möbius transform we can assume that $\partial D$ is the real axis and that the $z_k=x_k+i y_k$ $\>(1\leq k\leq n)$ lie in the upper half plane, whereby
$$y_k=1\quad(1\leq k\leq r),\qquad y_k>1\quad(r+1\leq k\leq n)$$
for some $r\geq1$. When $r=1$ the "circle" $y=1+\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$ will do. When $r\geq2$ we may further assume  $-a=x_1<\ldots<x_r=a$ for some $a>0$. A sufficiently large circle with center $iM$, $\>M\gg1$, through the points $z_1=-a+i$ and $z_r=a+i$ will then lie in the upper half plane and contain all the other $z_k$ in its interior. Now move this circle a small amount $\epsilon>0$ to the right, and it will contain all $z_k$ with $k>1$ in its interior, whereas the point $z_1$ will lie on the outside.

Comment: I don't know much about Möbius transforms, but thanks for the answer!